# Disable NE555 using an external microcontroller

Tags: arduino, reset, 555

I am trying to hack this board (it's a 60A PWM motor speed controller):
[image: 60A PWM motor speed controller]
Specifically, I need to enable/disable the 555 timer in the center using an Arduino. To accomplish that, it would be sufficient to drive the reset pin to low. **Currently, that pin is permanently connected to 0.66V (from a voltage divider)**.
I would like to obtain the following behaviour:

- when I set the arduino pin 7 to LOW, the timer should be OFF
- when I set the arduino pin 7 to HIGH, the timer should be ON

Using my bad knowledge of electronics, I came up to the following (partially working) circuit (mosfets are 2N7000):
[image: hack schematic]

When I set pin 7 to LOW, the timer is disabled, but viceversa the HIGH state is not working. What am I doing wrong?

These are the connection I am adding
[image: added connections]

EDIT: The idea and the circuit were correct, I was just connecting the wires wrongly! I inverted the drain and source pins of my mosfets! I swapped them as described in the schematic above and now everything works fine!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot disconnect the reset pin (4) of the 555 timer from +12V

Comment: Why not? If it's like an existing PCB, traces are just thin copper, easy to cut.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't want to have 12V permanently on pin 4, you need to disconnect it so it can be controlled.

Comment: Is there any way to reach my goal without cutting any trace from the existing circuit?

Comment: What exactly is this 555 doing? 0.66V, if correct, and if actually a DC voltage, is in between the guaranteed input thresholds of /RESET which seems quite unlikely for a professional design. Maybe it has some waveform on it?

Comment: The board is a PWM DC motor controller. This is the board I bought: https://it.aliexpress.com/item/32860306821.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2ita

Comment: You should add reference designators on your schematic, like R1, R2, R3, Q1, and Q2, as well as values. And you really should use a scope to observe waveforms, ripple, and noise, before attempting a hack. You can get an adequate scope for about $30.

Comment: Thank you @PStechPaul for the comment. I am going to add more labels and values to the schematic. Regarding the oscilloscope, I haven't got it. Can you suggest and link a good one for me?

Comment: A recommendation for an oscilloscope requires a lot more information on your spending budget, specifications, and seriousness about future projects. The DSO138 is a popular mini-scope that comes in kit form for about $30. There are also USB scopes in that price range. There are also scope-DMM instruments for $50-$100, and low end lab grade 100 MHz scopes for around $500. Also very nice used scopes on eBay.

Comment: Your circuit diagram doesn’t match your connection photo. You're connecting to the wrong side of the 4k7 resistor - you should be connected to the side of the resistor that's connected to pin-4 of the 555, not the 3.75V side.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I will update the picture with the true connection I am adding. By the way, if I connect the mosfet source directly to the reset pin (on the right of the 4.7k resistor), the 555 does not turn off when my gpio is low.

Comment: Your schematic was correct before - now it's wrong. The problem was in the pic of the PCB where you've put the new connection on the wrong side of the resistor - that's what needed to be fixed - not the schematic.

Comment: @brhans As you can read from the comment before yours, I tried what you're suggesting but "if I connect the mosfet source directly to the reset pin (on the right of the 4.7k resistor), the 555 does not turn off when my gpio is low". I will fix again schematic and picture!

Comment: So what voltage do you measure on the reset pin when your GPIO is low? What voltage to you measure on the gate pin of the MOSFET driving the reset pin? (and please label your components Q1, Q2, etc so that they can be referred to "by name").

Comment: You need to connect the DRAIN of the MOSFET to the reset pin, not the SOURCE, which should be connected to GND, as shown in the schematic..

Comment: @PStechPaul Sorry for the confusion... I always wrote SOURCE but I meant DRAIN

Comment: Thanks to both @brhans and PStechPaul suggestions, I found the problem! The idea and the circuit were correct, I was just connecting the wires wrongly! I inverted the drain and source pins of my mosfets! I swapped them as described in the schematic above and now everything works fine!!

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any reason why you shouldn't drive the 555's reset pin direct from the arduino's output pin without any transistors.

If you look at the NE555's data sheet you will see that the 555's reset pin only needs to be taken higher than about 0.7 V to take the 555 out of reset and enable it.

So, I can't see any reason why it is necessary to include transistors to take the reset pin all the way up to +12 V when just taking it above about 0.7 V will suffice.

Comment: I edited my answer since my measurements were incorrect. The reset pin is kept at 0.66V. Are you suggesting to connect the arduino pin directly to the reset pin??

Comment: @keyblade95 yes, I am suggesting to connect it directly, but not whilst the reset pin is tied to +12 V!

Comment: The second resistor of the voltage divider is about 1k. so a direct connection from a GPIO pin should be able to drive it high or low. If there is some sort of waveform on the reset pin, instead of a 0.66 VDC level (which seems unlikely), you can connect a Schottky diode from the Arduino to the reset pin, to hold it in reset with a logic low output.

Answer (score 1):

You have the drain of the first MOSFET tied to +5 V, and the gate of the second one tied to that. So the gate of the second MOSFET will always be at +5 V. Likewise, the drain of the second one is tied to +12 V, and the reset of the 555 is tied to that, so the reset will always be at +12 V.

You need to have some resistance between the drains and the supply voltages, and the sources of the MOSFETs should be grounded, this way when the MOSFETs are off the reset will be pulled high through the resistor, and when the MOSFETs are on it will be pulled to ground.

Imagine the MOSFET is a switch,
you have it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpMQpP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Reset is held high by being directly connected to 12 V, when the switch is closed all that happens is a little current passes through the resistor, reset isn't affected.

You need it to be like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKP188.png)</sup>

Reset is held high through the resistor until the switch is closed, which pulls it low.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also tried this configuration but the mosfet on the right is always off... I think there is a voltage divider between the 12 volts and the reset pin, I will edit my question to add this information